# How to find number of lags in autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction, autocorrelation

I am trying to using the tsfresh package in python in order to extract feature from accelerometer sensor input and I came across several features where they need lag variable:

```
tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.agg_autocorrelation(x, param)
Where:
                  x (numpy.ndarray) – the time series to calculate the feature of
                  param (list) – contains dictionaries {“f_agg”: x, “maxlag”, n} with x str, the name of a numpy function (e.g. “mean”, “var”, “std”, “median”), its the name of the aggregator function that is applied to the autocorrelations. Further, n is an int and the maximal number of lags to consider.
```

```
tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.autocorrelation(x, lag)
Where:
                  x (numpy.ndarray) – the time series to calculate the feature of
                  lag (int) – the lag
```

```
tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.c3(x, lag)
Where:
                  x (numpy.ndarray) – the time series to calculate the feature of
                  lag (int) – the lag
```

```
tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.partial_autocorrelation(x, param)
Where:
                  x (numpy.ndarray) – the time series to calculate the feature of
                  param (list) – contains dictionaries {“lag”: val} with int val indicating the lag to be returned
```

```
tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators.time_reversal_asymmetry_statistic(x, lag)
Where:
                  x (numpy.ndarray) – the time series to calculate the feature of
                  lag (int) – the lag that should be used in the calculation of the feature
```

So, I would like to know how to find the lag variable?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

TSFRESH is using lag variable as a parameter to calculate the relevant features.
 so for example in c3 calculation it will use lag=1 then lag=2, and by doing so will add the columns with calculated data as tsXcolname__c3__lag_1.

You should look up in TSFRESH how to change this parameter of how many lags it would calculate for each feature. I think that standard values are 3 for c3 and 9 for autocorrelations.